# ASP.Net delay, how can I tell if it is the client or the server?

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, delay

I've got a generic handler on a site.  When I go directly to it it responds immediately.  When I try to get to it from a .Net program, there is a long (10 second give or take) pause before the server is registering the request.

Here is the code I'm using to hit the server:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://MYURL/fs.ashx");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";

// This is the line that takes 10 seconds to return
StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);

streamOut.Write(sXMLToSend);
streamOut.Close();
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
HttpWebResponse resp = null;
resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
sResponse = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(sResponse);
resp.Close();
```

I don't think that this line was taking that long about a week ago, but I don't have any data to back that up.  Any ideas what the issue could be?  If I hit the url in a browser it responds **immediately.**  Are there any tools that I can use to figure out if it is my machine, or the server, or...I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: Just a wild guess, have you tried with just `http://` too? Maybe the application is trying to get/verify a certificate that the browser keeps cached.

Comment: try doing `var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream()` and see if that takes just as long; if it does, you can narrow down the search a little bit.

Comment: @Bala R var requestStream... caused the same delay.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but how does that narrow down the search?  I know that it at least eliminates the overhead that is needed to create a StreamWriter, but beyond that...I know I must be missing something.

Comment: @Matt I have no clue what the constructor of StreamReader does I wasn't sure if it was the GetResponseStream() or the StreamReader ctor that was causing the delay. Sorry if it was naive.

Comment: @SirViver -- Ok, so this is fun.  I switched to a different subdomain that had both http and https (the original one I was using is production so I didn't want to mess with it).  Now, https is taking 10 seconds to connect, but https is only taking 3 seconds.  It's still not instantaneous, but its better.  Is this just a DNS issue?

Comment: @Bala R -- I hope you didn't take offense to my comment -- I wasn't being snarky at all!  I was honestly asking if that was the narrowing down that you referred to.  If it came across sarcastic or condescending, I really apologize.

Comment: @Matt ha. it didn't come across sarcastic or condescending! for the question about dns issue, you should be able to find out if that's causing it by using the IP address directly.

Comment: Creating an HTTPS connection for a secure page is especially expensive, because
it involves browser and server agreeing on the key to encrypt content going over
the connection. The cost of creating a connection also goes up with geographical
distance. For example, it will be high if your server is in the US and your visitors are
in Europe

Answer (score 1):

Might it just be due to the fact that GetRequestStream is a synchronous method and its buffering it all up before returning? Maybe you should try calling the async version and process data as it comes in.

Comment: Ali, I don't think so -- at the time of the delay, I haven't even sent the XML document (via POST).  So, it's not like my code is waiting on the response yet.